# How to add multiple students to student class?

Tags: java, class, arraylist

Im trying to create a student class, a course class and the main class. I am trying to add students to the course, and when students are added to the class the number of students in the course should increase, when the the code is run it should print the course details followed by the students in the course.

I have got the following code:
Main class:

```
public class JavaLecture3 {
    public static final int DEBUG = 0;

    public static void main(String [] args){

        //Student student = new Student(); // Calling default constructor here.
        Course course = new Course();

        student = new Student(21, "Joe", "CSE", "07447832342");

        course = new Course("CSE", "Tom", 5);

        System.out.println("Course Information: ");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println(course);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Student contains: "); // calls student.toString());        
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println(student);
    }

}
```

Course class:

```
public class Course {

    ArrayList<Student> studentList;
    private String courseName;
    private String teacher;
    private int noOfStudents;

    //Getters
    public String getCourseName(){
        return this.courseName;
    }
    public int getNoOfStudents(){
        return this.noOfStudents;
    }
    public String getTeacher(){
        return this.teacher;
    }

    //Setters
    public void setCourseName(String courseName){
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }
    public void setNoOfStudents(int noOfStudents){
        this.noOfStudents = noOfStudents;
    }
    public void setTeacher(String teacher){
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    /**
     * Default constructor. Populates course name, number of students with defaults
     * 
     */
    public Course(){
        this.noOfStudents = 0;
        this.courseName = "Not Set";
        this.teacher = "Not Set";
        studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }

    /** 
     * Constructor with parameters 
     * @param noOfStudents integer
     * @param courseName String with the Course name
     * @param teacher String with the teacher
    */
    public Course(String courseName, String teacher, int noOfStudents){
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.teacher = teacher;
        noOfStudents = noOfStudents;
        studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    } 

   public static void addStudent(Student newStudent){
        if(studentList.size()==noOfStudents){
            System.out.println("The class is full, you cannot enrol.");
        }
        else {
            studentList.add(newStudent);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Course Name: " + this.courseName + " Teacher: " + this.teacher 
                + " Number of Students: " + this.noOfStudents;
    }
}
```

Student class:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public String gender = "na";
    private String course;
    private String phoneNo;
    public static int instances = 0;

    // Getters
    public int getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
    public  String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public String getCourse(){
        return this.course;
    }
    public String getPhoneNo(){
        return this.phoneNo;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        if (JavaLecture3.DEBUG > 3) System.out.println("In Student.setName. Name = "+ name);

        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setCourse(String course){
        this.course = course;
    }
    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo){
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }


    /**
     * Default constructor. Populates name,age,gender,course and phone Number 
     * with defaults
     */
    public Student(){
        instances++;
        this.age = 18;
        this.name = "Not Set";
        this.gender = "Not Set";
        this.course = "Not Set";
        this.phoneNo = "Not Set";
    }

    /** 
     * Constructor with parameters 
     * @param age integer
     * @param name String with the name
     * @param course String with course name
     * @param phoneNo String with phone number
    */
    public Student(int age, String name, String course, String phoneNo){
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

    /** 
     * Gender constructor
     * @param gender 
     */
    public Student(String gender){
        this(); // Must be the first line!
        this.gender = gender;

    }

    protected void finalize() throws Throwable{
        //do finalization here
        instances--;
        super.finalize(); //not necessary if extending Object.
    } 

    public String toString (){
        return "Name: " + this.name + " Age: " + this.age + " Gender: " 
                + this.gender + " Course: " + this.course + " Phone number: " 
                + this.phoneNo;
    }
}
```

Comment: so Course has an addStudent method. that would seem useful here

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy I dont understand?

Comment: `public static void addStudent(Student newStudent)` that method shouldn't be static!

Answer (score 0):

Since you initialized the array list in the Course class, you should add the students to it. You should create a method in Course that adds an object to the array list such as:

```
public void addStudent(Student s){
    studentList.add(s);
    noOfStudents++;
}
```

To add multiple students:

```
public void addStudents(Student[] students){
    for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
        studentList.add(students[i]);
    }
}
```

You're almost there, just use the .add method made for you in the array list.

Comment: But how would I add more than one student?

Comment: @anon1234 you can pass an array of students as an argument and add each student to the list. Going to update the answer in a second.

Comment: How would I enter the details of the students in the list, at the moment I am only able to enter one student from the main class by using `Student students = new Student(21, "Joe", "CSE", "07447832342");`

Comment: and when I put this code `course.addStudents(students);` in the main class I get the following error Student cannot be converted to Student[].

Comment: @anon1234 Of course you will get this error, you are trying to pass an object instead of an array of objects, try making multiple student objects then assigning them to one array and passing that array to the method. For example: 
`Student s1 = new Student();
Student s2 = new Student();
Student[] students = {s1,s2};
`
Then call the method.

Answer (score 0):

Reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html?is-external=true

Course.getNoOfStudents should just return studentList.size(). No need to maintain a separate variable.

To print a list of students (from Course):

```
for(int i=0;i<studentList.size();i++) System.out.println(studentList.get(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class JavaLecture3 {
public static final int DEBUG = 0;

public static void main(String [] args){

    //Create course object
    Course course  = new Course("CSE", "Tom", 5);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String cmd = "Yes";

    while(cmd.equals("Yes")){
       Student student = new Student();

       System.out.print("Enter a new student? ");
       cmd = scanner.next();

       if (cmd.equals("Yes")){
           //Read student name
           System.out.print("Enter a student name: ");
           String name = scanner.next();
           student.setName(name);

           //Read student Age
           System.out.print("Enter a student age: ");
           int age = scanner.nextInt();
           student.setAge(age);

           //Read student Course
           System.out.print("Enter a student course: ");
           String stdent_course = scanner.next();
           student.setCourse(stdent_course);

           //register the student to the class
           course.addStudent(student);
       }
    }

    scanner.close();

    System.out.println("Course Information: ");
    System.out.println("-------------------");
    System.out.println(course.toString());
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

I reworked a bit your toString() method from Course class. This should print the list of students attending a class.

```
public String toString (){
    String ret_value =  "Name: " + this.name + " Age: " + this.age + " Gender: " 
            + this.gender + " Course: " + this.course + " Phone number: " 
            + this.phoneNo + " Students attending this course:";

    for (Student student: studentList) {
        ret_value = ret_value + " " + Student.getName();
    }

    return ret_value;
}
```

Comment: But How would I add more than one student to the list?

Comment: create more student objects `student1 = new Student(21, "Alvin", "CSE", "07227832342");`

Comment: Is there way to implement it using a loop?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of how to read multiple users and add them to a course. I left a bit of code for you to fill on your own based on the example I wrote for the name of the student

Comment: Getting an error saying cannot find symbol variable student.

Comment: replace `student = new Student();` with `Student student = new Student();`

Comment: Also make sure you remove the last 3 lines of code because the student object is no longer defined in the main function. Once the for loop is finalized the object is destroyed and created again on the next iteration.

Comment: In order to print the course information you have to call the `toString()` method from the course class

Comment: You should also replace `public static void addStudent(Student newStudent)` with `public void addStudent(Student newStudent)`. I don't see any reason to make that method static, do you?

Comment: Instead of asking for how many students to add, can I make it to ask where they want to add students (yes or exit) and if they type yes then they can add a student and again ask the same question and if they type exit then it will print the results.

Comment: When I try printing out the details of the student using the code `System.out.println(student.toString());` I get the following error cannot find symbol variable student.

Comment: The student object is visible only inside the for loop. If you want to print the contents of the student objects you have to change the `toString()` method from the Course class, loop trough the array list contains the student objects and print their namea or whatever else your assignment requires.

Comment: sorry I don't quite understand. Could you explain a bit further please. Thanks.

Comment: I reworked a bit your `toString()` method from Course class to print the names of the students attending a class.

Comment: Thats fine but the problem is the student details such as the name, age is defined in the Student class and also the `toString` method for the student details must be in the student class and the `toString` method for the course details must be in the course class. And both `toString` should be printed out from the main class.

Comment: When you call `course.addStudent(student)` you save a reference of the student object inside the course class in the `studentList` array. This means you can access from within the Course class the student details for the students attending the course.

Comment: Do I call `course.addStudent(student)` from within the course class?

Comment: `course.addStudent(student)` is called from within the main function when you add a new student object to the course object.

Comment: When I add the code to the main function I get an error saying "I get the following error cannot find symbol variable student."

Comment: with what you need help?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class JavaLecture3 {
    public static final int DEBUG = 0;

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Student student = new Student(); // Calling default constructor here.
        Course course = new Course();

        student = new Student(21, "Joe", "CSE", "07447832342");

        course = new Course("CSE", "Tom", 5);
        course.addStudent(student);

        System.out.println("Course Information: ");
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println(course);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Student contains: "); // calls student.toString());        
        System.out.println("-------------------");
        System.out.println(student);
    }
}

public class Course {

    List<Student> studentList;
    private String courseName;
    private String teacher;
    private int noOfStudents;

    // Getters
    public String getCourseName() {
        return this.courseName;
    }

    public int getNoOfStudents() {
        return this.noOfStudents;
    }

    public String getTeacher() {
        return this.teacher;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public void setNoOfStudents(int noOfStudents) {
        this.noOfStudents = noOfStudents;
    }

    public void setTeacher(String teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    /**
     * Default constructor. Populates course name, number of students with
     * defaults
     * 
     */
    public Course() {
        this.noOfStudents = 0;
        this.courseName = "Not Set";
        this.teacher = "Not Set";
        studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor with parameters
     * 
     * @param noOfStudents
     *            integer
     * @param courseName
     *            String with the Course name
     * @param teacher
     *            String with the teacher
     */
    public Course(String courseName, String teacher, int noOfStudents) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.teacher = teacher;
        this.noOfStudents = noOfStudents;
        studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }

    public void addStudent(Student newStudent) {
        if (studentList.size() == noOfStudents) {
            System.out.println("The class is full, you cannot enrol.");
        } else {
            studentList.add(newStudent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Course Name: " + this.courseName + " Teacher: " + this.teacher
                + " Number of Students: " + studentList.size();
    }
}

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public String gender = "na";
    private String course;
    private String phoneNo;
    public static int instances = 0;

    // Getters
    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return this.course;
    }

    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return this.phoneNo;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        if (JavaLecture3.DEBUG > 3)
            System.out.println("In Student.setName. Name = " + name);

        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

    /**
     * Default constructor. Populates name,age,gender,course and phone Number
     * with defaults
     */
    public Student() {
        instances++;
        this.age = 18;
        this.name = "Not Set";
        this.gender = "Not Set";
        this.course = "Not Set";
        this.phoneNo = "Not Set";
    }

    /**
     * Constructor with parameters
     * 
     * @param age
     *            integer
     * @param name
     *            String with the name
     * @param course
     *            String with course name
     * @param phoneNo
     *            String with phone number
     */
    public Student(int age, String name, String course, String phoneNo) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.course = course;
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

    /**
     * Gender constructor
     * 
     * @param gender
     */
    public Student(String gender) {
        this(); // Must be the first line!
        this.gender = gender;

    }

    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        // do finalization here
        instances--;
        super.finalize(); // not necessary if extending Object.
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + this.name + " Age: " + this.age + " Gender: "
                + this.gender + " Course: " + this.course + " Phone number: "
                + this.phoneNo;
    }
}
```